# Code executed infinite times in threadpool because of exception

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, threadpool, asp.net-4.0

I've heard its bad to use ThreadPool in asp.net, however I've used it for the purpose of educating myself. My goal was to determine if the Application_Error event got fired (which is handled in the Global.asax) - my answer to that is: no, it does not get triggered.

But I had observed something strange. The thread I wrote simply queued up tasks to the threadpool. The task was meant to throw errors randomly. But I observed however that I keep frequently getting the error - the number exceeds the no. of times I've queued the task. A separate concern I have is even the `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()` isn't logging messages to my output window (visual studio). Why this strange behaviour?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace ThreadPoolDemo.Web
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(createthreads);
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
        }

        void createthreads()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);
            int i;
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Queueing items");
            for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ErrorTask), null);
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("End Queueing items");
        }

        void ErrorTask(object obj)
        {
            Random generator = new Random();
            int value = generator.Next(1);            
            if (value == 0)
                throw new Exception("Sample exception thrown");
            else
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Processed thread");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your `ErrorTask`. The first is that you're initializing a new `Random` instance every time the method is called. The default `Random` constructor seeds the random number generator with the value from `Environment.TickCount`, which will likely be the same for consecutive threads. So you'll get the same random sequence for multiple threads.

The bigger problem, though, is that `generator.Next(1)` will *always* return 0. `Random.Next(int max)` generates a random number, N, such that `0 <= N < max`. So your `ErrorTask` will throw the exception for every thread.

I have no idea how or why it would be throwing that exception more than once per call to `ErrorTask`. That doesn't seem possible.

I would suggest the following modification:

```
private Random generator = new Random();

void ErrorTask(object obj)
{
    int value;
    lock (generator)
    {
        value = generator.Next(2);
    }
    if (value == 0)
        throw new Exception("Sample exception thrown");
    else
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Processed thread");
}
```

`generator` now has class scope and is initialized only once. The `lock` is there to prevent multiple threads from trying to generate a number at the same time. Without the lock, the random number generator can get corrupted and it will start returning 0 on every call. And I changed the parameter to `generator.Next` to 2, so you can get numbers 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It was helpful. Did you try this in VS IDE? It happens within the IDE. However, on iis v5.1, I found that each time an exception happens, the `aspnet_wp.exe` process dies and re-appears with another process id. In the event logs there are 4 entries which corresponds to a single exception, i.e. the very first exception I guess. I suppose this is bad if it happens to a web site which maintains session data in the web server...

Comment: @deostroll: I didn't try to run your code. My observations are based on examining the code. Perhaps there's a good reason people discourage the use of the thread pool in asp.net applications.